# How to diff file and output stream "on-the-fly"?

Tags: python, diff, subprocess, pipe

I need to create a diff file using standard UNIX **diff** command with python **subprocess** module. The problem is that I must compare file and stream without creating tempopary file. I thought about using named pipes via **os.mkfifo** method, but didn't reach any good result. Please, can you write a simple example on how to solve this stuff? I tried like so:

```
fifo = 'pipe'
os.mkfifo(fifo)
op = popen('cat ', fifo)
print >> open(fifo, 'w'), output
os.unlink(fifo)
proc = Popen(['diff', '-u', dumpfile], stdin=op, stdout=PIPE)
```

but it seems like `diff` doesn't see the second argument.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use "-" as an argument to `diff` to mean `stdin`.

Comment: Then, you can pass `stdin=PIPE` to the `Popen` call, and then `proc.stdin.write(data)`.

Answer (score 8):

You could perhaps consider using the [difflib](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html#difflib-interface) python module (I've linked to an example here) and create something that generates and prints the diff directly rather than relying on `diff`. The various function methods inside difflib can receive character buffers which can be processed into diffs of various types.

Alternatively, you can construct a shell pipeline and use process substitution like so

```
diff <(cat pipe) dumpfile # You compare the output of a process and a physical file without explicitly using a temporary file.
```

For details, check out http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html